# Optimization error for pymc3

Tags: bayesian, pymc, multi-level, pymc3

I'm trying to create a relatively simple hierarchical bayesian model using pymc3.  I keep getting an error, however.  The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

# Example data.
ncond = 4
nSubj = 40
trials = 64

N = np.repeat([trials], (ncond * nSubj))
z = np.array([45, 63, 58, 64, 58, 63, 51, 60, 59, 47, 63, 61, 60, 51, 59, 45,
61, 59, 60, 58, 63, 56, 63, 64, 64, 60, 64, 62, 49, 64, 64, 58, 64, 52, 64, 64,
64, 62, 64, 61, 59, 59, 55, 62, 51, 58, 55, 54, 59, 57, 58, 60, 54, 42, 59, 57,
59, 53, 53, 42, 59, 57, 29, 36, 51, 64, 60, 54, 54, 38, 61, 60, 61, 60, 62, 55,
38, 43, 58, 60, 44, 44, 32, 56, 43, 36, 38, 48, 32, 40, 40, 34, 45, 42, 41, 32,
48, 36, 29, 37, 53, 55, 50, 47, 46, 44, 50, 56, 58, 42, 58, 54, 57, 54, 51, 49,
52, 51, 49, 51, 46, 46, 42, 49, 46, 56, 42, 53, 55, 51, 55, 49, 53, 55, 40, 46,
56, 47, 54, 54, 42, 34, 35, 41, 48, 46, 39, 55, 30, 49, 27, 51, 41, 36, 45, 41,
53, 32, 43, 33])
condition = np.repeat([0,1,2,3], nSubj)


# Specify the model in PyMC
with pm.Model() as model:
    # define the hyperparameters
    kappa = pm.Gamma('kappa', 1, 0.1)
    mu = pm.Beta('mu', 1, 1, shape=ncond)
    # define the prior
    theta = pm.Beta('theta', mu[condition] * kappa, (1 - mu[condition]) * kappa, shape=len(z))
    # define the likelihood
    y = pm.Binomial('y', p=theta, n=N, observed=z)
    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step1 = pm.Metropolis([mu])
    step2 = pm.Metropolis([theta])
    step3 = pm.NUTS([kappa])
#    samplers = [pm.Metropolis([rv]) for rv in model.unobserved_RVs]
    trace = pm.sample(10000, [step1, step2, step3], start=start, progressbar=False)
```

But I keep getting an error in regards to the find_MAP() function.  Can anyone explain this error to me?

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c4e40b20fd5c> in <module>()
     38     # define the likelihood
     39     y = pm.Binomial('y', p=theta, n=N, observed=z)
---> 40     start = pm.find_MAP()
     41     step1 = pm.Metropolis([mu])
     42     step2 = pm.Metropolis([theta])

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymc3/tuning/starting.pyc in find_MAP(start, vars, fmin, return_raw, disp, model, *args, **kwargs)
    124                          "density. 2) your distribution logp's are " +
    125                          "properly specified. Specific issues: \n" +
--> 126                          specific_errors)
    127     mx = {v.name: np.floor(mx[v.name]) if v.dtype in discrete_types else
    128           mx[v.name] for v in model.vars}

ValueError: Optimization error: max, logp or dlogp at max have non-finite values. Some values may be outside of distribution support. max: {'mu': array([ 14.66440283,  67.64627608,  36.73991444,  -2.27146408]), 'theta': array([ -3.28858534e+02,   1.49945045e+02,  -7.02150417e+01,
         9.97352990e-01,  -7.02150417e+01,   1.49945045e+02,
        -1.50195789e+02,   5.63428376e+00,  -9.29002815e+01,
        -2.70445580e+02,   1.49945045e+02,   1.03986058e+02,
         5.63428376e+00,  -1.50195789e+02,  -9.29002815e+01,
        -3.28858534e+02,   1.03986058e+02,  -9.29002815e+01,
         5.63428376e+00,  -7.02150417e+01,   1.49945045e+02,
        -5.57301509e+01,   1.49945045e+02,   1.01682005e+00,
         9.62368437e-01,   5.63428376e+00,   9.95206871e-01,
         5.88827819e+01,  -2.08511670e+02,  -7.51688112e+00,
         9.54524715e+00,  -7.02150417e+01,   1.02401342e+00,
        -1.24386722e+02,   1.00553699e+00,   1.00113792e+00,
         1.05862921e+00,   5.88827819e+01,   9.96530636e-01,
         1.03986058e+02,  -1.66473577e+02,  -1.66473577e+02,
         1.21070195e+02,   7.06961277e+01,   1.51469750e+02,
        -1.01158381e+02,   1.21070195e+02,   1.47085125e+02,
        -1.66473577e+02,  -5.55202522e-01,  -1.01158381e+02,
         5.37160225e+01,   1.47085125e+02,  -3.00112781e+01,
        -1.66473577e+02,  -5.55202522e-01,  -1.66473577e+02,
         1.58340576e+02,   1.58340575e+02,  -3.00112781e+01,
        -1.66473577e+02,  -5.55202521e-01,  -1.87830813e+01,
        -7.63325604e+01,   1.51469750e+02,   6.56687525e+02,
         5.37160224e+01,   1.47085125e+02,   1.47085125e+02,
        -7.30815598e+01,   5.20052822e+02,   5.37160224e+01,
         5.20052822e+02,   5.37160224e+01,   7.06961278e+01,
         1.21070195e+02,  -7.30815598e+01,  -1.20799887e+01,
        -1.01158381e+02,   5.37160224e+01,   2.55349034e+01,
         2.55349034e+01,  -1.42715299e+02,   3.77924839e+01,
         4.84747986e+00,  -1.07962425e+02,  -8.33028412e+01,
         1.00157336e+02,  -1.42715299e+02,  -5.22680519e+01,
        -5.22680519e+01,  -1.27123074e+02,   4.61912845e+01,
        -1.52905863e+01,  -3.44347435e+01,  -1.42715299e+02,
         1.00157336e+02,  -1.07962425e+02,  -1.65836239e+02,
        -9.64018880e+01,   1.06636770e+02,   6.59333401e+01,
         1.19873182e+02,   8.44063494e+01,   6.60981540e+01,
         2.55349034e+01,   1.19873182e+02,   3.77924839e+01,
        -3.45990714e+01,  -1.52905863e+01,  -3.45990714e+01,
         8.91977361e+01,   5.07494024e+00,   8.91977361e+01,
         1.21864768e+02,   1.12323534e+02,   1.17572851e+02,
         1.21864768e+02,   1.12323534e+02,   1.21864768e+02,
         6.29159569e+01,   6.29159569e+01,  -1.64948241e+01,
         1.05932671e+02,   6.29159569e+01,   1.85689051e+01,
        -1.64948241e+01,   9.30151996e+01,   4.81456147e+01,
         1.12276366e+02,   4.81456147e+01,   1.05932671e+02,
         9.30151996e+01,   4.81456147e+01,  -5.32061084e+01,
         6.29159569e+01,   1.85689051e+01,   8.03463229e+01,
         7.34110211e+01,   7.34110211e+01,  -1.64948241e+01,
        -1.29160807e+02,  -1.19831995e+02,  -3.54559256e+01,
         9.50334978e+01,   6.29159569e+01,  -6.95343458e+01,
         4.81456147e+01,  -1.61402820e+02,   1.05932671e+02,
        -1.92150490e+02,   1.12276366e+02,  -3.54559256e+01,
        -1.09378401e+02,   4.37180227e+01,  -3.54559256e+01,
         9.30151996e+01,  -1.45569868e+02,   3.34881430e+00,
        -1.37632194e+02]), 'kappa': array(1399.2675885517883)} logp: array(-inf) dlogp: array([         nan,          nan,          nan,          nan,
                nan,  -0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,
        64.16985826,  -0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,
         0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
        -0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        ,
        -0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,  66.50259666,   0.        ,  64.30823767,
         0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        ,
        -0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,  64.22281229,
         0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
        -0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
        -0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
        -0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
         0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
        -0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
        -0.        ,   0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
        -0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ])Check that 1) you don't have hierarchical parameters, these will lead to points with infinite density. 2) your distribution logp's are properly specified. Specific issues: 
mu.logp bad: -inf
theta.dlogp bad at idx: (array([160, 161, 162, 163, 164]),) with values: [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
theta.logp bad: -inf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means the optimization algorithm finished but returned values that don't make any sense. Usually this is because the maximum isn't well defined.

However, this actually worked fine for me. What versions do you have?

I have python 2.7, latest pymc3, theano 0.7.0, scipy 0.13